# Algebraic morphisms as covering spaces

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, covering-spaces

If $p : \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is a polynomial, $B \subset \mathbb{C}$ is the set of its regular values and $E = p^{-1}(B)$, then $p_{|E} : E \rightarrow B$ is a covering map of finite degree $\deg(p)$. I would like to know about the generalisations of this fact.

I know that if $S$ and $S'$ are compact Riemann surfaces, then any non constant holomorphic map $f : S \rightarrow S'$ is a ramified covering space thus we obtain a covering map after removing a finite number of points in $S$ and $S'$.

And if $X$ and $Y$ are complex algebraic varieties of the same dimension (we maybe need more hypothesis like separated or irreducible, I am not sure this is why I am asking this question) and $f : X \rightarrow Y$ is a dominant morphism, then there is a dense Zariski open subset $V$ of $Y$ such that $f_{|f^{-1}(V)} : f^{-1}(V) \rightarrow V$ is a covering map for the analytic topology.

Do you have any reference for that please ? I can't find anything.

Comment: What is your question here?

Comment: I need a reference to learn about it in general. If you want more specific questions : is it true that the complement of $V$ is always of codimension $1$ ? Is it always true that $y \mapsto \#(f^{-1}\{y\})$ is a lower semi-continuous function for the Zariski topology ?

Comment: @Cactus $f$ could just be any open inclusion, so $V$ need not have codimension $1$.

Comment: Yes of course, thanks ! I was assuming we could use some Hartogs like argument but it propably only work on particular cases like $X = Y = \mathbb{C}^n$.

Comment: An open subset $V$ as you describe exists. In Hartshorne's book 'Algebraic Geometry', III.10.7, p .272 it is shown that there is a $V$ such that $f^{-1}(V)\to V$ is smooth. By Chevalley's theorem (see exercise II.3.22 (e) in the same book, p. 95), you may assume (possibly after shrinking $V$) that the fibres of $f$ over $V$ are finite.

Comment: ... but you need to suppose that $X$ is non singular.

Comment: Ok I'll check it thanks !